# Street Fighter 1 Hadoken

Tags: street-fighter-series

Are there and if so what are the key combinations to perform the hadoken and the "multiple flying kicks" in Street Fighter 1?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Downvotes are when the voter thinks the question shows little or no attempt at research, or is unclear. Since the answer to this is easily found by using a search engine, and since the controls to perform a hadoken are different for different characters and you haven't mentioned which one you're asking about,  both reasons are probably why the downvote.

Comment: To clarify then, you can fix this by: a) doing a bit of research and indicating in the question the results of that research, and b) saying which character or characters you're trying to find the move controls for.

Comment: I have done research and couldn't find the answer.  I doubt this is "easily found."  If you know of a link, I'd appreciate that.  Also I am not sure what you mean by character, since in SF1 you only get to play Ryu (or Ken, but didn't think that makes a difference).

Comment: Answer coming right up.

Answer (score 2):

The [Street Fighter Wiki](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/) contains references for every move in the series.

[Ryu](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Ryu#Special_Moves)'s [Hadoken](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Hadoken) in every game is performed the same<sup>[1]</sup>: **⇓⇘⇒** <kbd>punch</kbd>

His [Tatsumaki Senpukyaku](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Tatsumaki_Senpukyaku) aka "Hurricane Kick" is<sup>[1]</sup>: **⇓⇙⇐** <kbd>kick</kbd>
(Though note that in SF1 this can only be performed on the ground, so a "multiple flying kicks" cannot be peformed.)

<sup>[1]</sup> The wiki has control graphics that you may find clearer, so refer to the linked articles.

Comment: It's worth noting that the controls in SF1 are ridiculously strict/finicky so it's possible that you might not have consistent success getting these moves to come out, even if you think you're doing it correctly.

Comment: Thanks!  But as cloudymusic points out, executing those moves consistently in SF1 seems impossible.  I've never seen anyone who's able to do that (though lot of time has passed).  Is it really possible to consistently obtain those moves using those combinations, or is there something else behind?  Is it really just a matter of precision?  I'll wait to hear what people ahve to see about this before accepting.

Comment: Here's a precise challenge: is it possible to program a software bot that will execute 100% of the time the hadoken in SF1? (I can't edit my previous comment.)

Comment: SF1 was known for having problems with processing the input buffer; simply put, the hardware and software weren't efficient enough to process the inputs correctly/fast enough to consistently or deterministically get the move out.  Even if you had automated inputs, you couldn't guarantee consistency.  It wasn't until Street Fighter II, with the CPS system that the the hardware was powerful enough for software to take advantage of to properly process an input buffer to consistently perform special moves.

Comment: @casperOne That sounds like it would be better as the core of an answer itself.

Comment: @casperOne Wow -- it's amazing to hear they had such mundane problems.

Comment: @EmanueleViola You have to remember, August 2017 is coming up on the 30th anniversary of Street Fighter.  The processing power at that time was minuscule compared to what's available now.

Comment: @casperOne sure, but SF1 was already featuring quite impressive graphics and more.  The problem you mentioned sounds to me more like a poor design choice.  I don't think there was any inherent hardware limitation back then that prevented a machine from recording the input moves.  By the way, do you have a reference for what you describe?  Thanks!